# Get previous name changes in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a graph API that returns me a list of previous name that were changed by the user.
One Way to do it manually is by going to Settings of your profile -> Download a copy of your Facebook data.
In the HTML files obtained it clearly mentions the previous names changed.

My question is there a graph API for the same ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

There are fields for name, first name and last name. You can only subscribe to updates, but afaik there is no way to get past changes. But since you are required to use your real name on Facebook, it should not happen very often - unless you marry a lot ;)

Comment: That's the only way. But you'll need an app for that, and maintain the according infrastructure for the realtime updates...

Comment: If the user has not published the name change on his/her time line its difficult to get that name change feed - I assume this. Thank luschn last line was a good one. I think the link was helpful, I can figure out a way.